# Initialize multiple variables at the same time after a type has already been defined in Java?

Tags: java

Need a little bit of help with syntax here. I'm trying to re-initialize multiple variables after the type has already been defined. So for example

```
int bonus, sales, x, y = 50;
```

This works fine... however I want to put a different value into some of those variables later on in my program, but I'm getting a syntax error.

`bonus = 25, x = 38, sales = 38;`

Compiler is saying I need

`another semicolon for bonus and x`.

Is there a way to change the values in a single line of code? Or would I have to put a semicolon after each value??

Comment: a semicolon after each statement.

Comment: In a line just separate the all variable with semicolon `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused as to be behavior of `int bonus, sales, x, y = 50;`. It initializes `y` to `50` and leaves the rest *uninitialized*.

To initialize all of them to `50`, you have to:

```
int bonus = 50, sales = 50, x = 50, y = 50;
```

You can then change their values:

```
bonus = 25;
x = 38;
sales = 38;

// or compact
bonus = 25;   x = 38;   sales = 38;

// or to same value
bonus = x = sales = 42;
```

Unlike the `C` language where you can use the comma syntax anywhere, in Java you can only use that when declaring the variables, or in a `for` loop: `for (i=1, j=2; i < 10; i++, j+=2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int bonus = 25;
int x = 38; // or any other value you prefer
int sales = 38;
```

later you can access the variables

```
bonus = 35; // and so on...
```

Answer (score -1):

Method: you can use it, this way.

```
int bonus=50; sales=50; x=50; y = 50;
```

In your code only y has been initialized.

if any help visit:
http://wwww.logic4code.blogspot.in/